# MS Test in VS 2017 with Multi-Targeted Reference Can't Some Load Assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mstest, .net-standard

### Setup

[Repro Project on Github](https://github.com/adraut/MixedFrameworkTests)

- A base library (Lib.Core) that targets both NetStandard 2.0 and NetFx 4.6.1 and references System.ComponentModel.Annotations.
- A consumer library (Consumer.Core) that targets NetStandard 2.0 and references the base library (Lib.Core) and references System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.4.0.0.
- A consumer library (Consumer.Full) that targets NetFx 4.6.1 and references base library (Lib.Core) and core consumer library (Consumer.Core) and references System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations 4.0.0.0.
- An MS Test project that targets NetFx 4.6.1 and references the NetFx consumer library (Consumer.Full).

### Problem

Executing the test results in the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

### Question

Is there something I need configure in the test project to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Lib.Core` project depends on the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` NuGet package. Since the `Consumer.Core` project references `Lib.Core` and only supports a netstandard2.0 target, this causes a reference to the higher assembly version than the framework included assembly to be part of the dependency closure.

Since the test project will not transitively acquire the NuGet package, you need to manually install the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` package into the test project. With this NuGet reference, the test passes.

Note that in this case the NuGet reference wouldn't even have been transitively acquired if the test project was an SDK based project (.NET Core Unit Test template with the target framework changed to `net461`) since the test project would only get references from the full-framework "slice" of the transitive project-to-project reference. (It can be discussed if this is a bug or not)

Comment: I understand why the direct reference doesn't pass through, but I don't understand how it thinks it needs a 4.2.0.0 version.  Is that buried in the facade between 4.6.1 and standard 2.0?

Comment: Yes the versions in .net standard are higher than in .net framework (see [here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute) for example) and even the assembly names are different. easiest fix is to install the NuGet package or change the test project to set `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</…>`